# Как в python определить день недели?

Tags: python

Делал я скрипт, который печатает день недели **в виде строки.**
Начал я с простого, чтобы **для начала выводилось целое число в виде номера текущего дня недели.** Посмотрел на сайтах, рекомендуют библиотеку **datetime**.
Использовал способ `isoweekday()`, вылезла ошибка:

[image]

Вот какой код я использовал:

```
from datetime import datetime

current_weekday = datetime.weekday()
print(current_weekday)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает, потому что метод weekday(), является методом экземпляра класса datetime, а не самого класса. Вы должны сначала создать экземпляр класса datetime, а затем, вызвать функцию weekday().

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
current_weekday = now.weekday()
print(current_weekday)
```

Этот код выведет целое число от 0 до 6, где 0 соответствует понедельнику, 1 - вторнику и т.д. до 6 - воскресенью.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно использовать этот способ с функцией isoweekday()? Эта функция выдаёт день недели так: понедельник - 1, воскресенье - 7.

Comment: Проверил - работает способ isoweekday()!

Comment: Спасибо, web developer